# Hash collision/limitation in IPFS: is it possible?

Tags: algorithm, hash, sha, ipfs

Let´s say that IPFS becomes an evolution of internet as we understand today, and the entire model (mainly websites and files that they store) migrates to be as decentralized as possible.

I am not sure about the entire procedure of how IPFS works under the hood, but I understood that the files will be stored mainly based on their hash.

**Is there a possibility that, due to the amount of files that a worldwide IPFS model can store (so then same amount of hashes will be generated), algorithms like SHA-2 reach a limit about the amount of unique hashes that it can generate (knowing that 2^256, which is pretty big)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to generate hashes for about **2^128** different files in order to find a single collision in a 256-bit hash by chance.

That number is much larger than the number of atoms in the universe, so the probability of that happening is extremely small.

It's much more likely that some problem will eventually be found in the hash function, allowing someone to create collisions on purpose.

Comment: Does this means that, whether I generate an SHA-2 from a file created in my local computer, that hash will be worldwide unique, and no one will generate same hash with another local and different file?

Comment: Effectively, yes